# External Links in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have the following code:

```
<div><strong>Name: </strong><?php echo anchor('http://'.$link, $row->Name); ?></div>
```

Which takes a users input for a link ($link) and puts the url into an anchor tag. It, however, is not redirecting to the external link but simply amending the base url for the site with the stored URL. I attempted to add 'http://' to the beginning of the submitted link which works unless the user has already supplied http in the link input. Any advice on how to overcome this would be amazing.

Comment: What version of CodeIgniter are you using? I just tried this in version 2.1 and the `anchor()` function does indeed check that it's external URL before creating application specific ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, [per the documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html), `anchor()` creates links based on your site's URL.

If things are working as expected when URL's are prefixed with `http://`, but you're having trouble with users sometimes adding `http://` and sometimes not, you could <strike>simply check the link to determine whether it's ok, or if you need to prefix it. Here's a basic example using [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):</strike>

```
if(strpos($link, 'http') === FALSE){
    // link needs a prefix...
    $link = 'http://' . link;
} else {
    // link is ok!
}
```

...use CodeIgniter's `prep_url()` function (thanks to [@cchana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/750593/cchana) for reminding me of it!):

> This function will add http:// in the event that a scheme is missing from a URL. Pass the URL string to the function like this:
>
> ```
> $url = "example.com";
>
> $url = prep_url($url);
> ```

Comment: Or you could use CodeIgniter's `prep_url()` function that takes care of it for you

Comment: @cchana: Ah, you're right! I *thought* there was a CI function for this but couldn't remember what it was. I'll add it to my answer. Thanks.